# Docker container can't find bundler/Ruby gems when I SSH into it, but works with "docker exec ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image successfully built, with the following properties:

1. It has bundler & Ruby gems installed for a Rails project, and successfully can run that project
2. It runs OpenSSH, and has a user set up with a private key so that I can SSH into it.  That user also has the ability to run `sudo` commands

When that container is up and running, if I run this command:

`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/sh`, then I am dropped into the console where I can successfully execute commands like `bundle exec rails console` in the project root directory.

However, if I SSH in, even if I become the `root` user (i.e. `sudo su - root`), then running that command gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.2.7) required by your /app/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.2.7`
```

It's as if it can't find any of the installed libraries, even though I can validate that they are present.  I can also validate that when I use the `docker exec...` command, I gain access as the root user.

I'm going in circles trying to figure out why I'm observing such a difference in behavior. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is generated since the exec can not find the `bundler` binary, or it finds a binary that is older version. In both cases, since you know that you have correct `bundler` installed, the problem will be in the `PATH` that is set. It's hard to tell what exactly is going on that is changing the `PATH`, but one thing to check is the initialization files for `bash` and `sh`.

To fix the problem, check the `PATH` environment variable (easiest check is `echo $PATH`) in both cases, and if required, set it up to the location of the `bundler` as follows:

In the session where it works, execute

```
~# which bundler
/usr/local/some_folder/bin/bundler
```

and in the session where you need it

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/some_folder/bin
```

You can add this to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` initialization files for the user in `ssh` and the `root`.

Answer (score 2):

The other comment put me on the correct path.  I ended up having to manually set these ENV vars to get things to work correctly.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bundle/bin
export BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
```